# Change Algolia instantsearch.js stats template

Tags: javascript, html, algolia

How could I change Change Algolia `instantsearch.js` stats template? (X results found in Y m/s)

According to [documentation](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#stats) it could be done via options.template, but that's it. Which variables represent *results count* and *time*, and perhaps other variables?

What is the best way to create a template?

This is what I have so far:

```
instantsearch.widgets.stats({
  container: '#stats'
})
```

Most probably I should add:

```
instantsearch.widgets.stats({
  container: '#stats',
  template: '#stats-template'
})
```

and then the template (what should be the variables?):

```
<script type="text/html" id="stats-template">
    <div data-reactroot="" class="ais-root ais-stats">
      <div class="ais-body ais-stats--body">
        <div>
          {{number of hits}} hits found
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates in *Algolia* work a bit differently, here is how your `instantsearch.widgets.stats` should look like:

```
instantsearch.widgets.stats({
  container: '#stats', // Your stats container
  templates: {
    body: getTemplate('stats') // Template for displaying stats
  }
})
```

and the template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="stats-template">
    <div data-reactroot="" class="ais-root ais-stats">
      <div class="ais-body ais-stats--body">
        <div>
          {{nbHits}} products found
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Full list of variables you can use in your stats template:

`hasManyResults, hasNoResults, hasOneResult, hitsPerPage, nbHits, nbPages, page, processingTimeMS, query`

More information: https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#stats

Comment: Just a note that the `getTemplate` method used here is not part of `instantsearch.js` and seem to be a custom helper that returns the content of the `script` tag.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example here: 
https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#templates

```
search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.stats({
        container: '#stats',
        templates: {
            body: function(data) {
                return 'Show ' + data.nbHits + ' results'
            }
        }
    })
);
```